# Number of zeroes of iterated function $f(x)=x^2-3/2$

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics, dynamical-systems, roots, iterated-function-system

This problem has been bothering me for a long time, and I come back to it every couple of months or so but can never seem to make any progress:

> Let $f(x)=x^2-3/2$. Consider the function
>   $$f^{\circ n}(x)=\overbrace{f(f(...f}^{n}(x)...)$$
>   What can be said about the number of real zeroes of $f^{\circ n}(x)$ for large values of $n$?

I’m sure that the number of zeroes grows exponentially $\sim a\cdot b^n$ for some $a,b$, but I can’t seem to calculate $b$. I can’t even come up with very satisfying bounds for $b$, even when I try looking for some self-similarity in the function $f$ that I might exploit.

Help?

Comment: Please link to [the previous version](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2935555/11619). Otherwise interested users may waste time reproducing earlier stuff.

Comment: I recalled commenting on a similar thread. It was [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2962644/11619).